# SphinxQL query does not return all matches

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx, sphinxql

I am usign SphinxQL to query Sphinx RT indexes.  Found that queries return 20 matches at most (20 seems to be a [default value](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setlimits)).

Tried adding options the `SELECT` query to change that limit to 1000:

```
SELECT [...] OPTION cutoff = 1000, max_matches = 1000
```

But got same results.

Is there a way to override the 20 matches result limitation using SphinxQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the LIMIT clause?

From the Docs:

> LIMIT clause. Both LIMIT N and LIMIT M,N forms are supported. Unlike in regular SQL (but like in Sphinx API), an implicit LIMIT 0,20 is present by default.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select